# For Custom Timer UI Surface view is better or Custom view?

Tags: android, performance, surfaceview, android-custom-view, countdowntimer

I want to show the count down timer in a custom circular progress bar. I have done this by invalidating the custom view's onDraw() method and Using CountDownTime api.

Can we use surface view using separate thread for this?, Also custom view is better or surface view is better?. Will there be synchronization of time if we use surface view using separate thread?

Comment: What does "better" mean, i.e. what about your current solution isn't working well?  If you use a separate thread you will need to forward the `CountDownTimer` update to the other thread.

Comment: In future I need to add animations to custom view. So it is better to use surface view right?.